# iOS - MPMediaPickerController - change barStyle

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution that works...

I'm developing an app that uses the MPMediaPickerController and creates a Modal view that allows the user to choose a song to play. My main view has a blackOpaque barStyle and I would like the Picker to have the same, but I cant seem to change the barStyle or color in anyway that I've tried. Here is the code snippet:

```
-(IBAction)showMediaBrowser:(id)sender  {
// Create a MediaPickerController object (alloc) and initialize with ONLY music type media
mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

// CK - Set properties
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Choose your song:";
mediaPicker.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

// CK - Present the model view and animate
[self presentModalViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES]; }
```

Thanks

Comment: If the `navigationController` is `nil`, try forcing it to load the view with `[mediaPicker loadView]`. Then set your toolbar style. If it's not `nil`, it could be being overridden during default loading/appearing behaviour. Try setting the toolbar style after `presentModalViewController:animated:`, with both `animated:YES` and `animated:NO`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible (likely) that the media picker doesn't have a navigation toolbar at the point in time that you are attempting to set the toolbar style.  Have you checked to see that `mediaPicker.navigationController` has a value ?

I'd recommend embedding the media picker controller into your own view hierarchy (the [docs for MPMediaPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) say it's possible), and then you will have complete control over the navigation bar from your own view controller.

```
// create media picker controller
mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

// set properties
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Choose your song:";

// get the media picker's view and set its frame
UIView *pickerView = mediaPicker.view;
pickerView.frame = myViewController.view.frame;

// add the media picker view to the view hierarchy
[myViewController.view addSubview:pickerView];
```